Angular mat-menu custom position
In angular material design, there is a mat-menu component. When it pops up, I want it to be positioned at the right side. I managed to find a solution on Stackblitz using Angular 10, but when I tried it with Angular 17, it doesn't work.
Is there a work around for Angular 17 to position the mat-menu on the right side?
Stackblitz Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-menu-position-aside
Issues: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/14621
I want the mat-menu to pop up on the right side using Angular 17.

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.
